# zypper - постоянно удаляет нужный пакет при update

Tags: linux

Суть проблемы в том, что постоянно поддерживаю систему в актуальном состоянии. Для этого применяю команду `update`. Менеджер пакетов с какой-то просто навязчивостью сносит один из необходимых мне пакетов. Поэтому приходится его переустанавливать после `update`. См. простыню вывода ниже.

```
gaal@linux-t420:~> sudo zypper update
Загрузка данных репозитария...
Чтение установленных пакетов...

The following 44 package updates will NOT be installed:
  bind-utils cvs cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-crammd5 cyrus-sasl-digestmd5
  cyrus-sasl-gssapi cyrus-sasl-plain dnsmasq git git-core git-cvs git-email
  git-gui gitk git-svn iscsiuio krb5 libdvdread4 libkqoauth0 libmbim-glib4
  libndp0 libqca2 libqjson0 libqmi-tools libsasl2-3 libstoken1 libvlc5
  libvlccore8 libxslt1 libxslt-tools mercurial mercurial-lang openconnect
  open-iscsi openssh openssh-askpass openssh-helpers perl-Net-SMTP-SSL rpcbind
  rp-pppoe rsync tnftp vpnc w3m

The following 4 NEW packages are going to be installed:
  kernel-default-4.1.27-27.1 kernel-default-devel-4.1.27-27.1
  kernel-devel-4.1.27-27.1 spectacle

The following package is going to be REMOVED:
  ksnapshot

The following 14 packages are going to be upgraded:
  dhcp dhcp-client google-chrome-stable ImageMagick kernel-macros
  libMagick++-6_Q16-3 libMagickCore-6_Q16-1 libMagickWand-6_Q16-1 nodejs
  nodejs-devel npm rabbitvcs virtualbox-guest-kmp-default
  virtualbox-host-kmp-default

14 packages to upgrade, 4 new, 1 to remove.
Общий размер загрузки: 121,2 MiB. Уже кэшировано: 0 B. После этой операции будет
использовано дополнительно 277,6 MiB.
продолжить? [y/n/? выводит все параметры] (y):
```

....

```
gaal@linux-t420:~> sudo zypper install ksnapshot 
root's password:
Загрузка данных репозитария...
Чтение установленных пакетов...
Разрешение зависимостей пакетов...

Проблема:Установка spectacle-15.12.3-11.4.x86_64 сделает устаревшим пакет ksnapshot < 15.12.3, предоставленный ksnapshot-15.08.3-5.1.x86_64
 Решение 1: удаление spectacle-15.12.3-11.4.x86_64
 Решение 2: не устанавливать ksnapshot-15.08.3-5.1.x86_64

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/о] (о): 

Разрешение зависимостей...
Разрешение зависимостей пакетов...

The following NEW package is going to be installed:
  ksnapshot

The following package is going to be REMOVED:
  spectacle

1 new package to install, 1 to remove.
Общий размер загрузки: 299,9 KiB. Уже кэшировано: 0 B. После этой операции будет
использовано дополнительно 223,9 KiB.
продолжить? [y/n/? выводит все параметры] (y):
```

Вопрос в том, как объяснить пакетному менеджеру, что не нужно удалять `ksnapshot` и устаналивать вместо него `spectacle`. А оставить все как есть, но просто обновить пакеты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот команда из [официального](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_manual_(plain)) мана:

```
zypper addlock ksnapshot
```

Comment: Спасибо, вывод поменялся. Вопрос - пакет будет обновляться в автоматическом режиме, если будут обновления?

Comment: @gecube, судя по тому, что написано в [man zypper](http://wiki.linux-club.de/opensuse/Man_zypper) (по поводу «Package Locks Management»), стоит заглянуть в `man 5 locks` (к сожалению, ссылки не нашёл).

Comment: @gecube, судя по тому, что написано в оф мане - нет, меняться не будет. Что может в будущем вызвать проблемы с зависимостями.

Comment: Жаль, получается половинчатое решение

Answer (score 2):

В `yast` под списком пакетов есть кнопка `Действия`. В выпадающем меню выберите пункт `Блокировать` для `ksnapshot`

Comment: через zypper никак? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я фанат консоли 0)))